# how to put the heading after the header() in android

Tags: android, textview

hi in the below I am fetching the data from database and getting the json response and displaying in an android table layout.But everything was working fine but i want to put some sub headings for displaying data for that I took the textview In that using setText() I am giving sub heading.But it's not displaying proper heading.

this output when I am running my app:

```
General registration
SI  Date        Toatal Registration
1   2015-04-01     2
2   2015-04-02     3
1   2015-04-02     3
```

Expected output:

```
    SI  Date        Toatal Registration
General registration
    1   2015-04-01     2
    2   2015-04-02     3
Ipd registration
    1   2015-04-02     3
```

**java**

```
public class Datewise_Patient_list extends Activity {

    String data = "",result="";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
   TextView si,tv;
    String queryString;
    int numOfPatients = 0;
   TextView[] snos;
    TextView[] date;
    TextView[] tot_reg;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.datewise_collection_report);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        final String date1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("date1");
        final String date2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("date2");


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                queryString = "date1=" + date1 + "&date2="
                        + date2;
                data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("DateWise_Collection_report",queryString);
                System.out.println(data);



                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<DateWise_Patients> datewisepatients = parseJSON(data);
                        numOfPatients = datewisepatients.size();
                        addData(datewisepatients);                     
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                queryString = "date1=" + date1 + "&date2="
                        + date2;
                result = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("DateWise_ipd_report",queryString);
                System.out.println(result);


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<DateWise_Patients> datewiseipdpatients = parseJSON1(result);
                        numOfPatients = datewiseipdpatients.size();
                        addData1(datewiseipdpatients);                     
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();


           }

    public ArrayList<DateWise_Patients> parseJSON(String data) {
        ArrayList<DateWise_Patients> datewisepatients = new ArrayList<DateWise_Patients>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                DateWise_Patients datewisepatient = new DateWise_Patients();

                datewisepatient.setDate(json_data.getString("date"));
                datewisepatient.setTot_reg(json_data.getString("total"));
                datewisepatients.add(datewisepatient);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
        }
        return datewisepatients;
    }
    public ArrayList<DateWise_Patients> parseJSON1(String result) {
        ArrayList<DateWise_Patients> datewiseipdpatients = new ArrayList<DateWise_Patients>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                DateWise_Patients datewiseipdpatient = new DateWise_Patients();

                datewiseipdpatient.setDate(json_data.getString("date"));
                datewiseipdpatient.setTot_reg(json_data.getString("total"));
                datewiseipdpatients.add(datewiseipdpatient);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
        }
        return datewiseipdpatients;
    }


    void addHeader(){
        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/

        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/

        si = new TextView(this);
        si.setText("SI");
        si.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        si.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);


        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

       Ll.addView(si,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.


        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView date = new TextView(this);
        date.setText("Date");
        date.setTextSize(15);
        date.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
        date.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        // pat_name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#075E93"));
         Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
         params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
         //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
         Ll.addView(date,params);
         tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.


         /** Creating Qty Button **/
         TextView tot_reg = new TextView(this);
         tot_reg.setText("Total Registrations");
         tot_reg.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         tot_reg.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         //reg_date.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#075E93"));
         Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
         params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
         //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
         Ll.addView(tot_reg,params);
         tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.


        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<DateWise_Patients> datewisepatients) {

        snos = new TextView[numOfPatients];
        date = new TextView[numOfPatients];
        tot_reg=new TextView[numOfPatients];


        int j = 0;


        addHeader();

        tv.setText("General Registration");


        for (Iterator i = datewisepatients.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {


            snos[j] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.si);
            date[j] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
            tot_reg[j]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tot_reg);



            DateWise_Patients p = (DateWise_Patients) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

           if(j % 2==0){
               tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00BFFF"));
           }
               else{

                   tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFE0"));
               }



            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
           snos[j] = new TextView(this);
           int temp = j;
           snos[j].setText(String.valueOf(temp +1));
           snos[j].setId(j);
           snos[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           snos[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
          // snos[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(snos[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.


            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            date[j] = new TextView(this);
            date[j].setKeyListener(null);
            date[j].setText(p.getDate());
            date[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            date[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
          //  patNames[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(date[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.


            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            tot_reg[j] = new TextView(this);
            tot_reg[j].setKeyListener(null);
            tot_reg[j].setText(p.getTot_reg());
            tot_reg[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tot_reg[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         //   regdates[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(tot_reg[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.


             // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            j++;
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
    public void addData1(ArrayList<DateWise_Patients> datewiseipdpatients) {

        snos = new TextView[numOfPatients];
        date = new TextView[numOfPatients];
        tot_reg=new TextView[numOfPatients];


        int j = 0;

    //  tv.setText("Ipd Patient List");




        for (Iterator i = datewiseipdpatients.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {


            snos[j] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.si);
            date[j] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
            tot_reg[j]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tot_reg);



            DateWise_Patients p = (DateWise_Patients) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

           if(j % 2==0){
               tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00BFFF"));
           }
               else{

                   tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFE0"));
               }



            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
           snos[j] = new TextView(this);
           int temp = j;
           snos[j].setText(String.valueOf(temp +1));
           snos[j].setId(j);
           snos[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           snos[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
          // snos[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(snos[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.


            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            date[j] = new TextView(this);
            date[j].setKeyListener(null);
            date[j].setText(p.getDate());
            date[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            date[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
          //  patNames[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(date[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.


            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            tot_reg[j] = new TextView(this);
            tot_reg[j].setKeyListener(null);
            tot_reg[j].setText(p.getTot_reg());
            tot_reg[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tot_reg[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         //   regdates[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(tot_reg[j],params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.


             // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            j++;
        }
    }
```